# How to suppress Pe070 error in IAR EW 8.1?

Tags: compiler-errors, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings, iar, error-suppression

I have to upgrade an IAR EW project from **V 7.80.2** to **V 8.10.1**.

My project worked without any warnings or errors in version 7.8. When I try to 
build exact the same project in version 8.1 I get the following errors (Pe070 / Pe065 / Pe020) These errors appear in my RTOS sources (SEGGER / emBos), so I'm not able to fix them right now.

My idea is to suppress these errors until IAR or my RTOS supplier has fixed theses errors. I tried it like this:

> [How to suppress warning (converted from error) in IAR EWARM 5.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26303415/how-to-suppress-warning-converted-from-error-in-iar-ewarm-5-4)

[image]

But it doens't work, the errors still occur.

Comment: Under the "Diagnstics" tab in "Suppress these diagnostics" try entering Pe070. It probably does the same thing that you are trying in a different way, but worth a go. It works for some stuff.

Comment: I already tried it... without any success

Comment: Googling the error codes it seems that these errors are (Pe020) missing identifier, (Pe065) syntax error, and (Pe070) using incomplete type. I don't know how you would expect to silence these. I suspect that you made a mistake on upgrade process.

Comment: No, the same code can be compiled with version 7.80 without any errors. It seems like a bug in the new version.

Comment: Is the code written in C++? The main compiler difference between 7.80 and 8.10 is that 7.80 compiles C++03 while 8.10 compiles C++14.

Comment: No, the code is written in C. But Version 8 uses C11 instead of C99 stabdard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not all errors that can be suppressed using --diag_warning or --diag_suppress. If the error is to severe the suppress option will be silently ignored by the compiler. Unfortunately there is no way to see which errors can be ignored an which can't.

Comment: That sounds very unprofessional... Can't believe that there isn't any documentation

Comment: I would personally prefer that you could determine from the error message if it is suppressable or not. There are thousands of errors to list.